# Can I safely delete .tmp files from a FoxPro 2.5?

Tags: foxpro

Can I safely delete `.tmp` files from a FoxPro 2.5 application?

There are currently over 71k `.tmp` files. They are located in the root directory and the `\TEMP` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete them, if they are in use you won't be able to delete them because they will be open exclusively. Foxpro usually creates these temp files when creating temporary cursors during program execution. Normally it should clean them up when the program terminates, but if it crashes these files will be left over.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is this

Check the timestamps on the files. If there are very old, delete them. If this is in Windows, deleting will not work if the are use.